# MySQL INSERT INTO / ON DUPLICATE KEY with SELECT statement issue

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1111

Howdy - I'm a MySQL Noob. I have a table of various business listings and I am trying to populate a second table called cities that contains unique city names along with a count of how many listings per city. I'm able to do a SELECT statement that gets me this data fine like so:

```
SELECT city,state,sum(count)
FROM (
SELECT city,state, 1 AS count FROM listings
) results
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY sum(count) DESC,city;
```

However, now I want to update the table, but I can't seem to get a proper statement to work. This is the latest that I have, but I'm currently getting a "Invalid use of group function" error.

```
INSERT INTO cities(city,state,size)
SELECT city,state,sum(count)
FROM (
SELECT city,state, 1 AS count FROM listings
) results
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), size=sum(count);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Would something as simple as this work?

```
insert into cities (city, state, size)
select city, state, count(*) as size from listings
group by city, state
```

`group by` should ensure that there are no duplicates so that there is no need for `on duplicate key`. The sum() + subquery thing you were doing looks like you were just trying to do a count(*).

The specific error you were getting was because of the size=sum(count). In a batch insert the correct way to do this would be size=values(size), see the docs on [`values()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values).

EDIT:

If it's adding another entry for each city then there isn't a unique index on city and on duplicate key won't do anything anyway.

if you add a unique index on (city, state) then you can add `on duplicate key update size=values(size)` to the above query and it will update each record in place.

Comment: I think we just posted the same query.

Comment: Hm, this works but it seems to be adding another entry for each duplicate city versus updating the previous entry. I guess that's what I was getting at by having the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" portion of the statement.

Comment: you don't need ON DUPLICATE KEY if you TRUNCATE the table first. but if you really want UN DUPLICATE KEY (which isn't really a bad approach) then you need to have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key on (city, state), which you probably don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though I wish I had something to test it on before unleashing it on you.

```
insert into cities (city, state, size)
select city, state, count(*) AS size
from listings
group by city, state
```