# INSERT... SELECT... WHERE... ON DUPLICATE... mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

Please help. I'm trying to update this one table with the current count of assets our products have. If the product already exist in the table, it should update the most updated count of the product. However, using the query below, mysql is returning me

> "ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function".

I can't determine what's my error or if it is really valid to use count in function 'on duplicate key':

```
INSERT INTO report_count_assets
    SELECT products.product_id, 
    count(product_assets.asset_id),
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=1 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=2 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=3 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=11 THEN 1 END) 
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_assets USING (product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN assets USING (asset_id)
    WHERE products.brand_id=671

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    asset_count = count(product_assets.asset_id),
    asset_type_image = count(case when assets.asset_type_id=1 THEN 1 END), 
    asset_type_video = count(case when assets.asset_type_id=2 THEN 1 END), 
    asset_type_sound = count(case when assets.asset_type_id=3 THEN 1 END), 
    asset_type_install = count(case when assets.asset_type_id=11 THEN 1 END);
```

Comment: this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function) may help u

Comment: Hi @diEcho, I'm not particularly looking for what products have this certain numbers in their assets. My concern is the update part of the query when the product is already present in the table. I don't know how select-join query can be implemented on 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can use aggregate functions in the [`ON DUPLICATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). MySQL sees your SQL sort of like this:

```
insert into report_count_assets
expr
on duplicate key update
...
```

The ON DUPLICATE doesn't know what's going on in `expr`, it only knows that it has a single duplicate row to deal with. Without knowing what's going on inside `expr`, there is no context for the `count`s to operate on. Also, you're supposed to use `values` in the UPDATE:

> You can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function in the `UPDATE` clause to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

And `values(count(x))` is not valid syntax. But `values(column_name)` is valid so this should work:

```
INSERT INTO report_count_assets
(product_id, asset_count, asset_type_image, asset_type_video, asset_type_sound, asset_type_install)
    SELECT products.product_id, 
    count(product_assets.asset_id),
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=1 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=2 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=3 THEN 1 END), 
    count(case when assets.asset_type_id=11 THEN 1 END) 
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_assets USING (product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN assets USING (asset_id)
    WHERE products.brand_id=671
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    asset_count = values(asset_count),
    asset_type_image = values(asset_type_image), 
    asset_type_video = values(asset_type_video), 
    asset_type_sound = values(asset_type_sound), 
    asset_type_install = values(asset_type_install);
```

I had to guess the name of the `product_id` column in `report_count_assets`.

If that doesn't work (as apparently it doesn't), then you can do it the hard way by precomputing the SELECT. Create a temporary table:

```
create temporary table t (
    product_id int,
    product_count int,
    assets1 int,
    assets2 int,
    assets3 int,
    assets11 int
)
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO t (product_id, product_count, assets1, assets2, assets3, assets11)
SELECT products.product_id, 
count(product_assets.asset_id),
count(case when assets.asset_type_id=1 THEN 1 END), 
count(case when assets.asset_type_id=2 THEN 1 END), 
count(case when assets.asset_type_id=3 THEN 1 END), 
count(case when assets.asset_type_id=11 THEN 1 END) 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_assets USING (product_id) 
LEFT JOIN assets USING (asset_id)
WHERE products.brand_id=671
```

And then use that temporary table to do the insert that you really want to do:

```
insert into report_count_assets
    select product_id, product_count, assets1, assets2, assets3, assets11
    from t
on duplicate key update
    asset_count = values(product_count),
    asset_type_image = values(assets1),
    asset_type_video = values(assets2),
    asset_type_sound = values(assets3),
    asset_type_install = values(assets11)
```

Comment: Hi @mu is too short, thank you so much! You saved a lot of blood of me.

Comment: @Jan-DeanFajardo: I have much nicer solution this morning if you're interested.

Comment: @Jan-DeanFajardo: You just use `values` inside the `ON DUPLICATE` section as in my update. I don't know what I was thinking with all that temp table stuff, [target fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_fixation) perhaps. I blame answering right before going to bed :)

Comment: well actually what you did about the temp table solved my problem. The values() inside ON DUPLICATE didn't work since it's only getting the current value of fields and not the updated value I'm getting from the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Jan-DeanFajardo: I put the temp table approach back, what ever works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by product_assets.asset_id:

```
.
.
WHERE products.brand_id=671
group by product_assets.asset_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    asset_count = count(product_assets.asset_id)
.
.
```

Comment: Also see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712240/mysql-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-with-select-statement-issue)